# How to record mouse and keyboard movement simultaneously, and store it as a variable that could be placed in a function or loop with Python?

Tags: python, automation, user-input

So I want to start a project that records my keyboard input and mouse movement for a sandbox PC games. I love farming, however whether I'm tired, and taking a short break to make a coffee or have a phone call. When I come back my farm gets annihilated.

I tried and made this one, but it seems not to work. Any way to make it better with the possibility to implement the recorded inputs in a loop function?

```
import pyautogui

def record_movement():
    # Initialize variables to store mouse and keyboard events
    mouse_events = []
    keyboard_events = []
    
    # Start recording mouse and keyboard events
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.001 # Set a small pause to record events more accurately
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False # Disable failsafe feature to allow for recording
    recording = True
    while recording:
        event = pyautogui.getEvent()
        if event.event_type == 'MouseMove':
            mouse_events.append(event)
        elif event.event_type == 'KeyDown':
            keyboard_events.append(event)
        elif event.event_type == 'KeyUp':
            keyboard_events.append(event)
        elif event.event_type == 'Quit':
            recording = False
    return mouse_events, keyboard_events

def replay_movement(mouse_events, keyboard_events):
    # Replay recorded mouse and keyboard events
    for event in mouse_events:
        pyautogui.moveTo(event.x, event.y)
    for event in keyboard_events:
        if event.event_type == 'KeyDown':
            pyautogui.press(event.name)
        elif event.event_type == 'KeyUp':
            pyautogui.keyUp(event.name)

# Test:
mouse_events, keyboard_events = record_movement()
replay_movement(mouse_events, keyboard_events)
```

Comment: "I tried and made this one, but it seems not to work." **What concretely happens** when you try it? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? **Did you try to check**, step by step, what is actually happening in the program when you try it? For example, does `replay_movement` get called? Do the passed-in `mouse_events` and `keyboard_events` values look right?

Comment: So the issue is that it becomes crazy once when during the stage of recording record input in the app or a game.

Comment: What does "becomes crazy" mean?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel teleporting mouse non stop, it was so fast that only 3 afterimages on whole screen was seen

Comment: Ah. So, think about what happens when you move the mouse around and press keys. Time elapses in between, right? Now, consider what happens when you **play back** the events. There are events that describe moving the mouse and events that describe pressing keys. Right? Are there events that describe allowing for certain amounts of time to pass? Is there other code in the playback routine, that would cause time to pass?